# HTTP GET to PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, http, get

Hello I have read many but need some help what I try to achieve is via the url to have "hey2" been passed to Javascript

It does not seem to work

http://mywebserver.com/test23.php?msg1=hey2

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://signage.me/demo/sendCommand.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#btn1").click(
         function() {
           sendCommand("galaxy.signage.me", "name@mail.com", "password", "13", "hey2", 
              document.test.msg1.value);  
           var msg1 = <?php echo(json_encode($msg1)); ?>;
         });
      });


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <?php

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
if (isset($_REQUEST['msg1'])) {
    $msg1 = $_REQUEST['msg1'];
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'var msg1 = ' . json_encode($msg1) . ';';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

Kind ask to post the changes to the code I am a newbie to understand changes just by suggestions(!)

so I take you suggest to do:

```
         <?php

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
if (isset($_REQUEST['msg1'])) {
    $msg1 = $_REQUEST['msg1'];
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'var msg1 = ' . json_encode($msg1) . ';';
    echo '</script>';
}
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://signage.me/demo/sendCommand.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#btn1").click(
         function() {
var msg1 = <?php echo(json_encode($msg1)); ?>;
           sendCommand("galaxy.signage.me", "user", "pass", "13", "new1", 
              document.test.msg1.value);  
         });
      });


    </script>
```

What do you thing on (still does not work!)

```
<?php ($msg1 = $_REQUEST['msg1']) {} ?> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://signage.me/demo/sendCommand.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#btn1").click(
         function() {
var msg1 = <?php echo(json_encode($msg1)); ?>;
           sendCommand("galaxy.signage.me", "name@mail.com", "password", "13", "hey2", 
              document.test.msg1.value);  

         });
      });


    </script>
```

Comment: Try putting your PHP-code before the actual HTML, so it's in the top, or at least above your other script. And skip the `header`-function. It'll probably throw an error, since it's mid-code.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `var msg1` in the click function. It's not being used there.

Comment: But the problem is that you haven't set `$msg1` yet, you only set it later in `$msg1 = $_REQUEST['msg1']`.

Answer (score -1):

just declare variable msg1 before it call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#btn1").click(
         function() {
var msg1 = <?php echo(json_encode($msg1)); ?>;
           sendCommand("galaxy.signage.me", "name@mail.com", "password", "13", "hey2", 
              document.test.msg1.value);  

         });
      });


    </script>
```

Comment: Or You can first write php script  code and after that write javascript code. and no need to write 'var msg1 = <?php echo(json_encode($msg1)); ?>;'.

Comment: could you please share how the code should look end2end

Comment: this is only part of the lot isn't it;